# How to launch a ML Training Job to Train a Tensorflow model using Azure ML SDK from Azure Devops

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to train a TensorFlow model using Azure ML SDK launched from Azure DevOps.

Currently, I use an Azure CLI task to launch the job.

```
az ml run submit-script -g $(ml.resourceGroup) -w $(ml.workspace) -e $(ml.DtExperimentName) --ct $(ml.computeName) -c cnn_training --source-directory . --path environment_setup -t ./metadata/cnn_run.json cnn_training.py --container_name  --model_path ./models/cnn_model.pkl --artifact_loc ./outputs/models/ --dataset_name data_ds
```

I also provide a training script and a config file.
The training script has no syntactical issues.

The config file is as follows:

```
framework: Python
script: cnn_training.py
communicator: None
autoPrepareEnvironment: true
maxRunDurationSeconds:
nodeCount: 1
environment:
  name: cnn_model_demo
  python:
    userManagedDependencies: false
    interpreterPath: python
    condaDependenciesFile: .azureml/conda_dependencies.yml
    baseCondaEnvironment:
  docker:
    enabled: true
    baseImage: mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/base:intelmpi2018.3-ubuntu16.04
    sharedVolumes: true
    gpuSupport: false
    shmSize: 10g
    arguments: []
history:
  outputCollection: true
  snapshotProject: true
  directoriesToWatch:
  - logs
dataReferences:
  workspaceblobstore:
    dataStoreName: workspaceblobstore
    pathOnDataStore: cccdata
    mode: download
    overwrite: true
    pathOnCompute:
```

The issue I face is that whenever I include TensorFlow as a requirement in the `conda_dependencies.yml` file, there is a disk full error issue.

Is there a way to structure this process to avoid this issue? I tried increasing the compute cluster size, I also changed the `shmSize` but had no luck. How should I proceed from here? Is there a better way to avoid the issue?

Comment: Some information needs to be checked. 1.Has your ML worked successfully before?  2.To troubleshoot code issues, did you try [Machine Learning  sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-tensorflow)? 3. Instead of running the azure cli task in azure devops, have you tried running the Azure CLI on your local machine?

Comment: The code with the TensorFlow model runs successfully in the azure ml notebooks. 
I have launched similar jobs via Devops which used sci-kit learn models and these ran successfully. Just that the same methodology doesn't work for Tensorflow.